# ERROR Inicializar proyecto en Netbeans, Maven y Spring Boot

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-boot, maven

estoy tratando de inicializar un un proyecto creado en Spring Initializr, lo exporto a Netbeans y a la hora de hacer click en "Clean and Build" para que me instale las dependencias que crea faltantes, me devuelve el siguiente error.

Algun iluminado que pueda ayudarme a resolverlo?

[image: ERROR]

ERROR TEST:

com.biblioteca.biblioteca.BibliotecaApplicationTests.contextLoads -- Time elapsed: 0.099 s <<< ERROR!

Errors:
BibliotecaApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@3234474 testClass =
com.biblioteca.biblioteca.BibliotecaApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.biblioteca.biblioteca.BibliotecaApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [],
activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"],
contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@c05fddc,
org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@50378a4,
org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4f0f2942,
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f,
org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7dc19a70,
org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@3baf781e], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader =
org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0[image: ERROR]

Comment: En principio ahí pone que te está fallando un test, que se está produciendo un error al tratar de ejecutarlo. Sin saber cuál es ese error, es dificil ayudarte. Intenta ejecutar los tests solamente y copia en tu pregunta el error que te sale ahí

Comment: @RubioRic Ahi pude dejarte el error del test hermano, disculpa.

Comment: Nada que disculpar, hombre. Era una sugerencia, no pretendía regañarte ni nada.

Comment: puedes agregar tu script de Test y las clases involucradas  ?

Answer (score 0):

Un solucion es crear el proyecto con spring initializr desde alli agregar todas las dependencias.
Si creaste el proyecto desde IDE, una solucion no recomendable, pero que te funcionara es la siguiente.

1. Confirmar en el archivo pom.xml si tienes el plugin maven-surefire-plugin
2. Si no lo tienes lo puedes agregar al archivo pom.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto, hara que configuración básica del plugin, La propiedad (testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore) indica que las fallas en las pruebas no detendrán la construcción del proyecto y se ignorarán.

Esto significa que, aunque haya fallas en las pruebas, el proceso de construcción continuará y no se detendrá debido a las fallas en las pruebas. Sin embargo, es importante tener en cuenta que ignorar las fallas en las pruebas puede ocultar problemas en tu código y no es recomendable en entornos de desarrollo y producción.

Saludos...